# Exclude only a top level directory in Metro Bundler using blacklist regex? (blacklistRE)

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native, metro-bundler

**I believe this to be primarily a question about regex**, but I may be wrong.

---

Let's say I wanted to exclude the folder in my project root called `art`.

**My output regex in the CLI looks like:**

```js
blacklistRE: /(all|the|other|matchers|art\.*)$/
```

**But this leads to an error:**

```
Unable to resolve "art/core/color" from "..\..\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ART\ReactNativeART.js"
```

How can I exclude the top level `art` directory without affecting all child directories?

**From the bundler's docs**

> **blacklistRE** 
>   Type: RegExp
>
> A RegEx defining which paths to ignore.
>   https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration/#blacklistre

**The code of the function I'm calling:**
It's short and self-contained in this file, if anyone better than me with regex might have any insight. https://github.com/facebook/metro/blob/8c53c38932c3e396109014ac707287fbdf2500d3/packages/metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist.js#L35-L44

**My full code looks like:**

```js
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

const regexStrings = [
  //  DEFAULTS
  '.*\\android\\ReactAndroid\\.*',
  '.*\\versioned-react-native\\.*',
  'node_modules[\\\\]react[\\\\]dist[\\\\].*',
  'node_modules[\\\\].cache[\\\\].*',
  'packages[\\\\]electron[\\\\].*',
  'node_modules[\\\\]electron.*',
  'website\\node_modules\\.*',
  'heapCapture\\bundle.js',
  '.*\\__tests__\\.*',
  '.*\\.git\\.*',
  // CUSTOM
  'art\\.*',
]

const constructBlacklistRE = () => {
  const formedRegexes = regexStrings.map(piece => new RegExp(piece));
  console.warn(formedRegexes);
  return blacklist([...formedRegexes]);
};

const config = {
  blacklistRE: constructBlacklistRE(),
}
```

Comment: This part of the pattern `art\.*` matces `art` followed by 0 or more times a dot literally, so matches could be `art`, `art.` or `art......` Try it without escaping the dot like `(all|the|other|matchers|art.*)$` to match any char instead.

Comment: are you want to convert const Color = require('art/core/color');  this line to const Color = require('core/color'); ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');
const path = require('path');

const ignoreTopLevelFolders = [
   'art'
   // add more top level folders here
].map(f => new RegExp(`${ path.resolve(f) }/.*`));

module.exports = { resolver: { blacklistRE: blacklist(ignoreTopLevelFolders) } };
```